# Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1 -why do I get this error while loading an xml file?

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1 -why I get this error while load xml file

this my code:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc=new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml("file.xml");
```

Comment: Your Xml is not valid - paste here the content

Comment: possible duplicate of [Data at the root level is invalid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5748668/data-at-the-root-level-is-invalid)

Comment: I just had this error on a resx file in Visual Studio and it was resolved by closing Visual Studio and opening it again.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The [`LoadXml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml.aspx) method is for loading an XML string directly. You want to use the [`Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/875kz807.aspx) method instead.