# How Read Xml File from Project Directory in C#?

Tags: c#

I need to know about to read xml file from project directory as shown below code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using crudpartialviewsjqueryajax.Models;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;

namespace crudpartialviewsjqueryajax.Controllers
{
    public class snehprajapatController : Controller
    {
        public void getinstructors()
        {
            try
            {
                List<string> name = null;
                XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
                xml.LoadXml(@"~\App_Data\Trainings.xml");//Here given xml path location
                XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/Trainings/Training");

                foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
                {
                    new List<string>{ xn["name"].InnerText };
                }
            
                //return name;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.dll
>
> Additional information: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

Please see the above code and suggest what to do to fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1 -why do I get this error while loading an xml file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7544475/data-at-the-root-level-is-invalid-line-1-position-1-why-do-i-get-this-error-w)

Answer (score 1):

`LoadXml` is for loading a literal XML string, not for pointing to a file path.  Your path is, not surprisingly, not valid XML. You can use `xml.Load("...")` to load into an `XmlDocument` from a file.

However, I'd *strongly* suggest you use LINQ to XML instead unless you have a very good reason to be using the old `XmlDocument` API.  I've made a guess based on your code, though this may not work correctly if your XML isn't structured this way.

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(@"~\App_Data\Trainings.xml");

var instructorNames = doc.Descendants("Training")
    .Elements("name")
    .Select(e => e.Value)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should replace the xml.LoadXml by the method xml.Load because :
[XmlDocument.Load](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.load.aspx) : is for loading XML either from a stream, TextReader, path/URL, or XmlReader.
While the [XmlDocument.LoadXml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml.aspx) is for loading the XML contained within a string.

so your code should be like that :

```
xml.Load(@"~\App_Data\Trainings.xml");//Here given xml path location
```